# How do I create two frames with no space between them?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have two frames with no space between them. Here's my test case:

```
<html>
  <frameset framespacing="0" rows="50%, 50%">
    <frame frameborder="0" src="red.html" scrolling="no" noresize="1" />
    <frame frameborder="0" src="red.html"                             />
  </frameset>
</html>
```

red.html is just:

```
<html><body bgcolor="red"></body></html>
```

When I render this, however, I get a white line between the two frames. How do I make it go away?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example of working code that I have used in the past that has no white line.

```
    <frameset rows="10%,*" noresize framespacing=0 frameborder=no border=0 >
       <frameset cols="140,*" noresize framespacing=0 frameborder=no border=0 >
          <frame name="globe" scrolling="no" src="./GIF/globe.jpg" marginwidth="0 marginheight="0">
      <frame name="logo" src="logo.htm" scrolling="no" >
</frameset>
      <frameset cols="160,*" noresize framespacing=0 frameborder=no border=0 >
      <frame name="userselections" src="userselections.php" scrolling="auto">
      <frame name="results" src="nothing.htm" scrolling="auto">
   </frameset>
   <noframes>
      <body>
         <p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>
      </body>
   </noframes>
</frameset>
```

Comment: That isn't valid markup. There should be closing `frame` and `frameset` tags. It also looks like the "This page uses frames..." bit should be inside a `noframes` tags.

Answer (score 10):

You need to specify the FrameBorder property in the Frameset tag.
So, your main page will look like this:

```
<html>
  <frameset framespacing="0" rows="50%, 50%" frameborder="0">
    <frame frameborder="0" src="red.html" scrolling="no" noresize="1" />
    <frame frameborder="0" src="red.html"                             />
  </frameset>
</html>
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <frameset framespacing="0" rows="50%, 50%" framespacing="0" frameborder=no>
    <frame frameborder="0" src="red.html" scrolling="no" noresize="1" />
    <frame frameborder="0" src="red.html"                             />
  </frameset>
</html>
```

frameborder=no is very important.

Answer (score 1):

It is always preferred to use css styles instead of frameborder attribute.

```
<frameset cols="50%,50%">
<frame src="frame_1.htm" style="border:none">
<frame src="frame_2.htm">
</frameset>
```

Better to use iframe and divs where ever possible.

**Further frameset is not supported in HTML5.**

Answer (score 0):

Add border=0 to your frameset tag.

Comment: I had that answer 5 minutes ago... but pasting the code into the answer box totally screwed up the page rendering in chrome.